# AWS Identity Pool Attributes for access control

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-cdk

I am trying to use the **aws-cdk** to create the cognito stack (User pool and identity pool) along the IAM roles, but I don't seem to be able to configure on the Identity Pool, the **Attributes for access control** on the cognito authentication provider to be able to add principal keys for the custom mapping:

[Identity Pool Attribute Access Control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soxuz.png)

If anyone could help me I appreciate it, my code for creating the identity pool is this:

```js
const identityPool = new CfnIdentityPool(this, "IdentityPool", {
  allowUnauthenticatedIdentities: false,
  cognitoIdentityProviders: [{
    clientId: userPoolClient.userPoolClientId,
    providerName: userPool.userPoolProviderName,
  }, ]
});

// Create authenticated role
const authenticatedRole = new Role(this, "AuthenticatedRole", {
  assumedBy: new FederatedPrincipal(
    'cognito-identity.amazonaws.com', {
      "StringEquals": {
        "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud": identityPool.ref
      },
      "ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
        "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr": "authenticated"
      },
    }, "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity")
})

// Create authenticated role
const unauthenticatedRole = new Role(this, "UnauthenticatedRole", {
  assumedBy: new FederatedPrincipal(
    'cognito-identity.amazonaws.com', {
      "StringEquals": {
        "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud": identityPool.ref
      },
      "ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
        "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr": "unauthenticated"
      },
    }, "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity")
})

new CfnIdentityPoolRoleAttachment(this, 'IdentityPoolRoleAttachment', {
  identityPoolId: identityPool.ref,
  roles: {
    "authenticated": authenticatedRole.roleArn,
    "unauthenticated": unauthenticatedRole.roleArn
  },
  roleMappings: {
    mapping: {
      type: "Token",
      ambiguousRoleResolution: "Deny",
      identityProvider: `cognito-idp.${Stack.of(this).region}.amazonaws.com/${
        userPool.userPoolId}:${userPoolClient.userPoolClientId}`
    }
  }
})
```